# making test account admin of a facebook page using graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

can we make a test account admin of a page on facebook, using facebook graph api?

I have created test users for a facebook app, but when i try to access the page using api, it just gives back the real world data, is there a way to read the test data posted on the app's wall?